# How to correctly style a form?

Tags: html, css

I'm really not that good at CSS, and I want to know how to correctly style a form in a manner that it puts each single text input and label in a line. like this :

```
<label for="input1">...</label>
<input type="text" id="input1"/>
<label for="input2">...</label>
<input type="text" id="input2"/>
<label for="input3">...</label>
<input type="text" id="input3"/>
<label for="input3">...</label>
<input type="text" id="input3"/>
```

and it would be shown in the webpage like :

```
(label)(input)
(label)(input)
(label)(input)
(label)(input)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [this tutorial by A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms/) about Prettier Accessible Forms.  You can also use a definition list with some custom styling, e.g.,

```
<dl><dt><label></label></dt>
  <dd><input></dd></dl>
```

And something like:

```
dl dt {
    float: left;
    width: 8em;
}
```

**Edit:** to sum up the A List Apart article, they suggest you put form fields in an ordered list `ol`.  Labels are displayed as `inline-block` so they appear horizontally next to their associated fields.

Comment: I don't understand. putting form elements in definition list is kind of non semantic.

Comment: I'm marking this as an answer because of the link provided, it helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
<label>foo</label>
<input type="text"/>
<label>foo</label>
<input type="text"/>​

<style>
input, label { float:left  }
label { clear:left; }
</style>
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/RpRS5/

Comment: I believe this is the best way to get this. +1

Answer (score 1):

Put them in a list, or in a structure like a list (that is to say, wrap each "row" in a div).

Comment: this should have been a comment.

Comment: @AnubhavSaini How so? It's a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

Put your inputs inside the label element and then you can simply `display: block` them or float them, I prefer display but it would be easy enough to change.

`<label>Hello <input type="radio" name="what" value="Hello" /></label>`

http://jsfiddle.net/Bpxfp/

Comment: But isn't this a bad practice ?

Comment: @Rafael "this"? What are you referring to?

Comment: Putting inputs inside label tags.

Comment: @Rafael The w3c demonstrates this usage and calls it "implicitly associated" http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ud7YE/1/

you can control the space between the label and input by varying the width of the wrapper. Just set the height of the label and the top margin of the input same in value but negative

Comment: one good way to solve. but floating and `margin`-lizing is bad for code maintainability

Answer (score 0):

I find enclosing label and input or select tags in a div or list. And the label and select tags should be of type `inline-block`

```
<div>
    <label>Name: </label><input type="text" />
</div>

<div>
    <label>Place: </label><input type="text" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
}
input {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px;
}
div {
    display: block;
    margin: 2px 0;
}
```

This would work out well.